# How to extract JSON from response body in Gatling

Tags: scala, performance, gatling

I am using Gatling and want to extract JSON from the response body and then use jsonPath on that. To be clear the response is something like this:

```
<html>
<!-- usual stuff here -->

<script>
/* JSON I WANT TO EXTRACT */
{
var1:'val1',
var2:'val2'
}
</script>

<!-- rest of HTML content -->

</html>
```

I am able to get the JSON using regex:

```
val chain = exec(http("Homepage")
    .get("/")
      .check(regex("""myJsonRegex""").find(1).saveAs("responseJSON"))
```

That's not the actual regex, but not the point, the regex works and I can isolate the JSON, but I would really like to use jsonPath on that saved "responseJSON", not sure how to do that. I can probably just do the whole thing with regex, but it would be much cleaner with jsonPath.

Comment: There's nothing native in Gatling to handle that, but you can do it with one of the other JSON scala frameworks. You'll have to manually parse the string returned from your .regex in a session function

Answer (score 0):

You could use `circe` or more specifically `circe-optics` for that. The [documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html) has a few decent examples.